# Is it possible to operate two RAID-0s alternately?

Tags: raid, software-raid, raid-0

I have a software RAID-0 (two hdds) on a WIN7 machine that holds all footage of a video project. If I remove and store these drives and install two new drives as RAID-0 for another project, will I be able to reattach the stored drives and find my data intact?

In short: Is it possible to operate two (software) RAID-0s alternately by simply switching drives or will I lose data if I do so?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I made a backup and simply tested it. Turns out it works! However, I'd advise that you also make a backup if in the same situation - no guarantee from my side!